# How can I embed the YouTube field module in a specific page?

Tags: files

Shifting from Wordpress, I'm quite a newbie at Drupal. So I want to embed the YouTube field module in a specific page, not just on the landing page (as it is shown in the setup video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzvEEMO0_Ug). But how can I do this? I somehow just can't figure out where I can select the page I want it to be on. Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are designed to be attached to pieces of content (entities), especially the main content entities (nodes). Using youtube field, would mean you can attach a different youtube video to every type of content. This likely results in a textfield on every node edit page (of that certain content type) where you enter a URL or something.

If that is what you want, proceed happily. If you go to the manage display section of your content type you can alter the `teaser` view mode (switch in the right top) and remove the field from display so it does not show on the front page.

If that is not what you want and you only want one block to appear in a sidebar or something, go to the blocks page, create a new block and just paste the embed code there. Make sure to set the content filter to `full-HTML` so it does not get sanitized. Each block allows you to specify the URL's on which it should be displayed. (There is no need for this module)

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. The second case you described is true. So what do you mean by "just paste the embed code there"? the youtube link? Because that's what I did but it ended up just showing the link and no youtube video at all... The block exists and shows up so I'm asking myself if I still need to add something...

Comment: If you go to the video on youtube, choose `share` (below the video) and then choose `embed` you get a textfield with a value like this: `<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` That is what you should put in the block.

Answer (score 1):

In the video, he creates a content type called "Youtube Field". (This is a confusing name, if you ask me. Maybe he should've named the content type "Youtube Pages"

**You do not have to** do this (**create a new content type**).

> But how can I do this? I somehow just can't figure out where I can
>   select the page I want it to be on. Thanks a lot for any help

Sounds like you already have a content type on which you created Pages (called `nodes` in Drupal).

So all you have to do is add the youtube field to your Article content type (the Article content type comes by default when you install Drupal) **Assuming that you used Article content type to create your pages. Maybe you used Basic Page? or Maybe you created a new content type? let's assume it is Article for the rest of this answer**

you need to MANAGE FIELDS of your article content type (`/admin/structure/types/article/display`) and add a new field:

Label: Example >> Field Type: Youtube video.

Now when you add a new article / or **in your case edit your nodes**, you will have your Example field where you just paste the youtube url.